# Simple Java Decryption Program Error

Tags: java

I'm trying to work on a problem that takes for example abcdef and encrypts it using a numeric key such as 3. that means all letters are shifted 3 letters down to yield defghi

Eventually the program will ask for a textfile input, output textfile, and the key in the commandline.

I'm running into an error with my current code. The encyption is faulty.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Program
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException  
    {
```

here is the error:

```
java Program 1.txt 2.txt 6
Encrypted:ghiJklM
Decrypted:uvwXyzA
```

Comment: Don't repost your question...

Comment: i was told i should make a new question if it is a different problem? sorry i'm new here. but the decryption is not shifting the letters by 6. g -> u = 14

Comment: The code example is largely incomplete, can you post more?

Answer (score 2):

You are decrypting the original `String`, not the encrypted one.

The first two lines of your decryption algorithm should read:

```
for(int j = 0; j < encrypted.length(); j++) 
{
    int current1 = encrypted.charAt(j);
    ...
```